# How to prove the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded, which satisfies the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=\ln |a_n|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

When I browsed **Zhihu**(a Chinese Q&A community), I met this question. That is

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be recursive s.t.
>   $$a_1=2,\ a_{n+1}=\ln |a_n|(n\in \Bbb N).$$
>   Show that $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

I want to investigate a subsequence $\{a_{t_n}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$, where $t_n$ is greatest integer satisfying
$$a_{t_n}=\min_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}a_k.$$
Thus $a_{t_n}\to -A(<0),n\to \infty$.

However, it helps little with the origin question. So how can I solve it ?

Comment: Ok a few observations that might help: first it would be better to consider $a_{n+1}=|\ln(x)|$ it is equal to $|a_n|$ so both problems are equivalent.

Comment: Secondly: If we assume $a_n$ to be bounded we get by Bolzanno Weierstrass that $(a_n)_n$ has a limit point and that point cannot be $+\infty$ or $0$ or $1$ or any number of the form $e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{...}}}$ since applying $f(x)=|\ln(x)|$ would give us a limit point at $\infty$ in all cases

Comment: Thirdly: Suppose $x^*\ne 0$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_n$ and let $(a_n)_{n_i}\to x^*$ then by continuity of $f$ we have that $(f^k(a_n))_{n_i}\to f^k(x^*)$ ( spacing out the $n_i$s by k if needed so that $n_{i+1}-n_i>k$). With this in mind we can easily prove that every point of the sequence $(f^n(x^*))_n$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_n$ and in fact every limit point ${x_1}^*$ of $(f^n(x^*))_n$ is also a limit point of $(a_n)_n$.

Comment: Four: Every limit point will give us another limit point in the interval $(0,x_0)$ where $x_0\in (0,1)$ is the fixed point of $f$.

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Thanks for your hints, but I think we can't solve this question only with them.

Comment: Yes I don’t think so too but it might save people a few extra minutes of thought

Comment: I think any proof would have to rely on very specific properties of the number $a_1 = 2$, since the set of points with finite orbits under $x \mapsto \ln|x|$ (particularly the subset of points which eventually reach the fixed point of this map) seems like it might be dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think that the fact the fixed point is “repelling” plays some part in that, so the points with finite order will probably not end up being dense

Comment: A [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EwvK.png) of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ for $n\le 30000$ looks rather chaotic.

Comment: I've been struggling to prove it, but if you look at the graphs of the functions $y = f^k(x)$ (where $f(x) = \ln |x|$) for $k = 1, 2, \dots$, it really seems like the set of points which eventually reach the fixed point becomes dense -- in fact it seems that on any open interval $I$, there's some $k$ for which the image of $I$ under $f^k$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes but that would be a good thing because then you’ve got $a_n$ unbounded. The fact a subsequence if points converges to the fixed point isn’t something bad necessarily either, you only need a subsequence diverging to infinity

Comment: If you were to get that the graph of 2 is dense somehow in $\mathbb{R}$ for example you would get a subsequence converging to every point but then you would also get an unbounded subsequence

Comment: The thing is as a dynamical system it is really interesting so maybe if we could somehow show it is equidistributed wrt some measure on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and translate that integral into an integral wrt the Lebesque measure that would settle it. BUT the $|\ln| function makes this really hard as it forced an exponent somewhere so maybe we should assume it is bounded and then normalize the interval and try for a measure there

Comment: that's the issue though -- it wouldn't immediately imply that $a_n$ is unbounded; if the sequence $a_n$ reaches the fixed point $x_0$ ("reaches", not "converges to"), then it stays there forever and the sequence is bounded. but if the condition I mention above holds, i.e. the set of points reaching $x_0$ (after finitely many steps) is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then it seems like it would be extremely hard to prove that $2$ is not in this set

Comment: to be clear, the condition I mentioned doesn't imply that the sequence $x, f(x), f^2(x), \dots$ will always be dense (we know values of $x$ where this is false), it means the union of preimages $\{x\}, f^{-1}(x), f^{-2}(x), \dots$ will always be dense

Comment: You mean for every $x$ in your last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107381/discussion-between---and-user125932).

Comment: Can I have that Zhihu's link@RocYeats

Answer (score 5):

*Note:* This discussion relies heavily on results from [my answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660738/532432). Any references to numbered theorems below refer to theorems from there.

---

Showing that this sequence is bounded would require showing that it is not cyclic, which I believe is not solvable with our current knowledge of exponentiation. To see why:
If $a_K = 2$ for some $K\in \mathbb{N}$, then we would have $$
\ln|\ln|\cdots \ln 2|| = 2
$$
or equivalently $$
2 = e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots^ 2}}}
$$
for some appropriate sequence of $+$'s and $-$'s. It would be a miracle if this existed, but given that simple facts like [whether $e^{e^{e^{e^e}}}$ is an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Open_questions) are unknown, my guess would be that proving it's impossible would require some ground-breaking techniques. It's also presumably unknown whether or not there exists a sequence of $+$'s and $-$'s such that $$
2 = e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots ^{\pm e}}}}
$$
which would imply that the sequence blows up after finitely many iterations.
[Theorem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660738/532432) implies that both $$
\left\{e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots ^{\pm e}}}}\right\} \mbox{  and  } \left\{e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots ^{2}}}}\right\}
$$
are dense in $[0,\infty]$, so there's no computational way to check whether $a_n$ is periodic or terminates in finite time.

I can show that "most" starting values for the sequence are bounded (but I can't quite prove "almost all" - see below). By [theorems 1 and 2,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660738/532432) for all $x$, there exists a sequence $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence of functions $$
x_n(t) = e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\cdots ^{\epsilon_{n-1} e^{\epsilon_n t}}}}
$$
converges uniformly to $x$. Alternatively, we can write $$
x = e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\epsilon_2 e^{\epsilon 3 e^{\cdots}}}} := [\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...]
$$
Note that if $(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n)$ are all $1$, then $x> {^{n-1}e} $, where the left superscript represents tetration. Borrowing my notation from the above referenced answer, $L_n(x)$ is the $n$th term of the sequence formed by iterating $\ln |x|$, and is given by $$
L_n(x) = \epsilon_n \cdot [\epsilon_{n+1},\epsilon_{n+2},\dots]
$$
If $\epsilon_n$ are chosen randomly, then for any $M\in\mathbb{N}$, with probability 1 there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon_{m+1},\cdots,\epsilon_{m+M+2}$ are all $1$. Then$$
|L_m(x)| \ge {{^M}e}
$$
Hence with probability 1, the sequence $L_n([\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dots])$ is unbounded.

I also proved the following representation for the distribution function of $[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...]$:$$
F(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n\mathrm{sgn}(L_k(t))}{2^{n+1}}
$$
which looks a lot like a binary digital representation. Notice that if $t = [\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...]$, then $$
\mathrm{sgn}(L_n(t)) = \mathrm{sgn}(\epsilon_n \cdot [\epsilon_{n+1},\epsilon_{n+2},\dots]) = \epsilon_n
$$
Let $t = [\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...]$ and  $$
\beta_n = \frac{1+\prod_{k=1}^n\mathrm{sgn}(L_k(t))}2
$$ Note that $\beta_n$ is always $0$ or $1$, and $\beta_0=1$, so $$
F(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n\mathrm{sgn}(L_k(t))}{2^{n+1}} = \frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\beta_n - 1}{2^{n+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta_n}{2^n}
$$
Hence $\beta_n$ gives exactly the binary digits of $F(t)$. As we already observed, the event that $L_n(t)$ has probability $0$, where $t=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots]$ is given the distribution that $\epsilon_n$ are chosen i.i.d. uniform on $\{-1,1\}$. But the above computation shows that if $t$ has this distribution, then $F(t)$ has the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, since the $\epsilon_n$'s are mapping to the binary digits of $F(t)$. Let $S = \{t : L_n(t) \mbox{ is a bounded sequence}\}$. We then have $$
F(S) = \{y\in(0,1) : y\mbox{'s binary expansion does not have arbitrarily long sequences of 1's}\}
$$
Because $F(S)$ has measure $0$, I believe that $S$ also ought to have measure $0$, but I'm not sure how to show $F$ has this property. It would suffice to show $F^{-1}$ is absolutely continuous, which it does appear to be, though it might be tough to prove. This same method *does* show that the set of points that are eventually periodic is countable and dense (since it corresponds to rational points in the image of $F$, which is continuous and bijective).

---

Update: I think I do see how to show $F^{-1}(x)$ is actually Lipschitz continuous on any $[\alpha,\beta]\subset[0,1)$. It involves applying the uniform convergence of the $x_n(t)$ functions to their limits. It would be rather tedious to write out the details since it seems necessary to have a large proliferation of cases to check. I don't have time to work through it at the moment, but I will update this answer when/if I do.

Comment: Ah I never thought about that unsolved problem! It would seem really hard to prove the result for a specific value if it is still open. I suggested the same representation in my comment above so I perfectly understand your reasoning, however sadly even almost all wouldn’t guarantee an answer...it does make for a very interesting question though regarding this dynamical system

Comment: Indeed it seems we had the same idea. It would be even more difficult to prove whether any particular value enters a bounded yet aperiodic sequence under iteration of $|\log t|$, since the set of such points is uncountable (though I suspect measure 0).

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment

1) Some equivalent recurrences:

As in Μάρκος Καραμέρης's comment, one may consider the equivalent recurrence: 
$$a_1 = 2; \ a_{n+1} = |\ln a_n|, n\ge 1.\tag{1}$$ 
Thus, we have
$$a_1 = 2; \ \mathrm{e}^{a_{n+1}} + \mathrm{e}^{-a_{n+1}} = a_n + a_n^{-1}, \ n\ge 1$$
or
$$a_1 = 2; \ \cosh a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + a_n^{-1}}{2}, \ n \ge 1$$
or
$$a_1 = 2;\ a_{n+1} = \operatorname{arccosh} \frac{a_n + a_n^{-1}}{2}, n\ge 1.\tag{2}$$
(note: $\operatorname{arccosh} x = \ln (x + \sqrt{x^2-1})$, $x\ge 1$)

Let $b_n = \frac{a_n + a_n^{-1}}{2}$. We have
$$b_1 = \frac{5}{4}; \ b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{arccosh} b_n + \frac{1}{\operatorname{arccosh} b_n}\right), n\ge 1. \tag{3}$$

2) In [1], consider the following problem: Is the sequence $\{x_n\}$ unbounded?
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{1}{x_n}, \ x_0 = 2.$$
Is the approach there helpful for this problem?

*Reference*

[1] Marc Chamberland, and Mario Martelli, "Unbounded orbits and binary digits", 2003.
http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~chamberl/papers/mario_digits.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but is too long for the usual comment format. Below is a numerical example where the initial value is very close to $1$ but the sequence is bounded. This suggests that showing the sequence is unbounded will use very specific properties of $2$ and will therefore be hard.

As in Μάρκος Καραμέρης's comment, I find it more convenient to use the equivalent recurrence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where $f(x)=|\ln(x)|$ (rather than $f(x)=\ln(|x|)$).

Since $f^{4}(0.44) \geq 0.48$ and $f^{4}(0.45) \leq 0.40$, it follows that $f^{4}$ has a fixed point $\beta\in [0.44,0.45]$.

Any $x\gt 0$ has two preimages by $f$, namely $E(x)=\exp(x)$ and $G(x)=\exp(-x)$. Also, we have $a_{k}=E(a_{k+1})$ when $\ln(a_k)\gt 0$ and $a_k=G(a_{k+1})$ otherwise. So, there is a well-defined sequence $(F_k)_{k\geq 1}$ with values in $\lbrace E,G \rbrace$ such that $a_k=F_k(a_{k+1})$ for all $k$.

Now, define a sequence $(b_k)_{1\leq k \leq 396}$ backwards (why $396$ ? because $a_{396}$ happens to be close to $\beta$), by putting $b_{396}=\beta$ and $b_k=F_k(b_{k+1})$ for all $k$.

Using PARI-GP with 200 digits precision (see program below), one can see that
$b_1$ is very close to $2$ : $|b_1-2|\leq 10^{-100}$. On the other hand, if we start from $b_1$ rather than $a_1$, we get a sequence that is eventually $4$-periodic (and therefore bounded).

```
\p 200
f(x)=abs(log(x))
large_number=396
an_sequence=vector(large_number,k,[]);
an_sequence[1]=2
for(k=2,large_number,an_sequence[k]=f(an_sequence[k-1]))
/* check a good approximation for beta */
f4(x)=f(f(f(f(x))))
betaa=444651345712468867357552650044449620720822557574794055208951851149593925469515592545042756658149233979242459023501275506326633186564851181962848935531478012975488666361285767551984962547168811/(10^192)
check_betaa=abs(f4(betaa)-betaa) /* is around 4E-192 ; that's good */
/*Construct the (bn) sequence backwards */
bn_sequence=vector(396,k,[]);
bn_sequence[396]=betaa;
for(j=1,395,\
k=396-j;\
bn_sequence[k]=if(log(an_sequence[k])>0,exp(bn_sequence[k+1]),exp(-bn_sequence[k+1]));\
)
see_difference=abs(bn_sequence[1]-an_sequence[1])
```

Comment: One thing I said in the chat is that if you want to find $k$-periodic orbits, just look at infinite tetrations. In fact, they can give you examples of orbits of arbitrary size, which is very interesting! (the fixed point $x_0$ is exactly the infinite tetration of $e^{-1}$ for example). Alternating the ± signs one can manually construct such a sequence. Although I don't see that it is useful to solve our problem...

Comment: Exactly as @Bcpicao said it, if you consider just the signs you get a binary representation (with $1$ iff the corresponding sign is $+$ and $0$ otherwise). You then have $0$ corresponding to the fixed point and $0.000...1010...$ with $k$ $0$s corresponding to a sequence arbitrarily close to $0$ that becomes periodic after $k$ iterations. You are correct in your formulation though and that 2 will definitely play a role

Comment: Can we prove that $a_n$ is well-defined for all $n$? It could be a problem if at some step we hit exactly $e$ or $1/e$, then the next point would be $1$, the next after than would be $0$, and from there it breaks because $f$ is not defined at zero. In a sense, the sequence would become unbounded too early.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It is natural to extend $f$ to $[0,\infty]$ by putting $f(0)=f(\infty)=\infty$. This way, $(a_n)$ is always well-defined for all $n$.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain their reasons ?