# Convergence of probabilistic power tower $e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{...}}}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, power-towers

While pondering over [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642899/how-to-prove-the-sequence-a-n-is-unbounded-which-satisfies-the-recurrence), I came across another interesting one. I am familiar with infinite tetration and its convergence over the reals. Nevertheless, when I saw this power tower, I couldn't help but wonder which distributions of $\pm$ signs make this converge or diverge.

For instance: $$e^{-e^{-e^{...}}}={}^\infty(e^{-1})< \infty \\ e^{e^{e^{...}}}={}^\infty e \to \infty$$

Let's define $\forall n\geq 1,\epsilon_n \in {\pm 1}$ as the *n*th sign of the power tower $$P_\epsilon=e^{\epsilon_1e^{\epsilon_2e^{...}}}$$

defined recursively as $$
[P_\epsilon]_1(x) =e^{\epsilon_1 x}\\ [P_\epsilon]_{n+1}(x) = [P_\epsilon]_{n}(e^{\epsilon_{n+1} x})\\ [P_\epsilon]_n(e) = [P_\epsilon]_n\\
$$

Then, evidently, the first terms of $\epsilon_n$ are irrelevant, only the assymptotic behaviour is important. If we take $$\epsilon_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{for } n\equiv 0 \mod k \\-1 &\text{else }\end{cases}$$

would this converge for some $k$?

Lastly, one can conjure of all sorts of patterns for these $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}:$
what if the $(-1)$s are only for prime indexes? What if $\epsilon$ is $−1$ with probability $(1−p)$ and $1$ with probability $p$?

I think this last question is very interesting, but probably hard to solve. It would seem an important threshold occurs if the expected value $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon)=0$, or $p=\frac{1}{2}$, as the limit case for convergence is $${}^\infty(e^{e^{-1}})<\infty$$

My guess is, for $\epsilon$ with $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon)>0$ it will diverge a.s. and for $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon)<0$ it will converge a.s., but I have no idea on how to prove it.

This reminds me a lot of Kolmogorov's three series theorem, although I doubt it can be solved in a similar manner. I hope I haven't missed something that would make this problem trivial, that would be very disappointing. Thanks! (feel free to edit to make it look better, or to add more appropriate tags)

**EDIT**:This question has been edited to account for the non-associativity of exponentiation, a fact I, somehow, seemed to have momentarily forgotten.

Comment: This question seems interesting, but it could be written way better. Notations such as $0[k]$, $\mathbb{E}$ and $P_{(-1)^n}$ are not clear. The definition of $P_\epsilon$ could be written as a recursive formula instead of just saying it's a power tower. Instead of "if $\epsilon$ takes its values following a biased Rademacher distribution, with probability $p$", you could simply say "if $\epsilon$ is $-1$ with probability $(1-p)$ and $1$ with probability $p$" to make it clear for all of us.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The notations of [ ] to denote modulus and $\mathbb{E}$ to denote expected value are canonical in France, where I study, I thought they would be clear. I'm going to edit as best as I can following your suggestions, feel free to tweak the question yourself if you want!

Comment: @Paul I have been unable to find a recurrence formula for $[P_\epsilon]_n$, will you help me?

Comment: I think the easiest way to get a recursion is like this: Define a function $[P_\epsilon]_n(x) = e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\cdots^{\epsilon_n x}}}$. Then the recursion is $[P_\epsilon]_{n+1}(x) = [P_\epsilon]_{n}(e^{\epsilon_{n+1} x})$ and you have $[P_\epsilon]_n(e) = [P_\epsilon]_n$.

Comment: I would also like to point out, because exponentiation is not associative, ${^\infty}(e^{e^{-1}}) \ne \exp(P_{(-1)^n}) = e^{e^{-e^{e^{-e^\cdots}}}}$

Comment: The right-hand side converges to exactly $e$, whereas the left-hand side converges to about 1.31. One can easily see $P_{(-1)^n} < 1$ because it's $e$ to a negative power. This guarantees $\exp(P_{(-1)^n}) < e$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Thank you! That was exactly what I meant with my comment to Marcus's answer! It seems I foolishly played around with these expression without realising this idiotic mistake. One could easily find a counterexample to what Marcus prove with my bogus rules, and that was how I realised my mistake. Although it did seem odd to me that neither him nor Paul spotted that ^^

Comment: @Bcpicao Yes it is an easy mistake to make. Exponentiation is weird so sometimes it can be difficult to see what's going on. By the way, I do hope you get a chance to read my answer. I think Marcus's proof of convergence is cleverer than mine. But there's a lot of other interesting things that can be said about these power towers than only their convergence properties.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Of course! I'm sorry I'm taking so long to do so but I've been quite busy today. I already skimmed through it, but I'll comment on it once I've done a thorough reading. I just want to say thank you for the huge smile you put on my face when you said you really enjoyed my question, your enthusiasm meant a lot and it totally made my day!

Comment: You're welcome! No rush, it is obviously rather long; I just thought it would interest you so I didn't want you to move on after getting the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I believe that if any of the $\epsilon_n=-1$ for $n\ge 1$, then the value of the expression converges. Allow me to explain why.

Before I start, this is my first bounty, so I'm not really sure what the rules and standards of proof are. I know I could've gone into more detail, but I don't think it would've helped with understanding the proof, and I think the lemmas I skipped over would be fairly obvious/intuitive and tedious to prove. I'm open to feedback, but I think my response answers the question well.

Conventions:

- $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$
- $[x,y]=\{z\in \overline{\mathbb{R}} \mid x\le z\le y\}$
- $[x] = [x,x] = \{x\}$. If $a=[x]$, then $a$ is unique.
- $\mu([a,b])=b-a$ is the standard measure on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

This means that $\exp([a,b])=[e^a,e^b]$ and $-[a,b]=[-b,-a]$, where $e^{-\infty}=0$ and $e^{\infty}=\infty$.

We are studying the "reverse-sequence" of sets $a_{n-1}=\exp(\epsilon_na_n)$, where $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\cdots)$ and $\epsilon_n\in\{-1,1\}$ for $n\ge 1$.  My understanding of convergence is that if $a_{\omega}=\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ for some transfinite number $\omega$, then $a_0$ will be unique, containing a single value.

There are three cases: $\epsilon$ contains no $-1$s, $\epsilon$ contains finite $-1$s, and $\epsilon$ contains infinite $-1$s. If $\epsilon$ contains no $-1$s, then $a_0=\exp(\exp(\exp(\cdots)))$. It is pretty clear that $a_0=[\infty]$. However, as I will prove, this is the only case where $a_0$ diverges in any fashion.

If $\epsilon$ contains a finite number of $-1$s, then let $n$ be the last number such that $\epsilon_n=-1$. We know that $a_n=\exp(\exp(\exp(\cdots)))=[\infty]$, so $a_{n-1}=\exp(\epsilon_na_n)=\exp(-[\infty])=[0]$. Then, $a_0$ is a finite sequence of exponentials away from $a_{n-1}$, so $a_0$ is also finite and unique.

Now, let's consider the case where there are an infinite number of $-1$s. Let $\omega$ be some transfinite number where $\epsilon_{\omega}=-1$. By "transfinite" I mean that if $b(\omega)_n=a_{\omega-n}$, then $a_0=\lim_{\omega\to\infty}b(\omega)_{\omega}$. (Yeah, it's not great notation, but I'm sure you can figure out what I mean.)

We know that $a_{\omega+1}\subseteq[-\infty,\infty]$. Assuming the worst case scenario, let $a_{\omega+1}=[-\infty,\infty]$. Then, $\epsilon_{\omega+1}a_{\omega+1}=\pm[-\infty,\infty]=[-\infty,\infty]$, and $a_{\omega}=\exp(\epsilon_{\omega+1}a_{\omega+1})=\exp([-\infty,\infty])=[0,\infty]$. This means that $a_{\omega-1}=\exp(\epsilon_{\omega} a_{\omega})=\exp(-[0,\infty])=[0,1]$.

Let $\Omega=(\Omega_0,\Omega_1\ldots)$ be the sequence of values less than or equal to $\omega$, in descending order, such that $\epsilon_{\Omega_i}=-1$. Also, let's define a function $E:\left(\{1,2\ldots\}, [0,\infty]\right)\to [0,1]$ such that: $E(1,x)=e^{-x}$ and $E(d+1,x)=E(d,e^x)$ for $d\ge 1$. Then, it is easy to see that $a_{\Omega_{i+1}-1}=\exp(-\exp(\exp(\cdots\exp(a_{\Omega_i-1}))))=E(\Omega_{i+1}-\Omega_i,a_{\Omega_i-1})$. I claim that not only is $\mu(a_{\Omega_{i+1}-1})<\mu(a_{\Omega_i-1})$, but the decrease is large to justify that $\lim_{i\to\infty}\mu(a_{\Omega_{i}-1})=0$, for any difference $d=\Omega_{i+1}-\Omega_i$.

This is because $E(d,x)$ is Lipschitz-continuous for all $d$ on $[0,1]$, with Lipschitz coefficient $K=1$. In fact, for $d > 1$, $K$ is much smaller. Unfortunately, when $d=1$, $e^{-x}$ has a slope of $-1$ at $x=0$. Because the Lipschitz bound is only touched at one point on the edge, we can write that $|x-y|>K|E(d,x)-E(d,y)|>|E(d,x)-E(d,y)|$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$. This means that $\mu(E(d,a))<\mu(a)$, for any set $a\subseteq[0,1]$. Furthermore, because $E$ is a smooth function, there can be no "catch-points" where the decay of the size of $a$ would stop. Therefore, after an infinite number of passes through $E$, the size of $a$ would approach $0$.

This means that if we start from progressively larger values of $\omega$, the size of $a_0$ will be calculated to be smaller and smaller, so that in the limit $a_0$ will have size $0$. Therefore, $a_0$ is unique. Therefore, the value of the expression $\exp(\epsilon_1\exp(\epsilon_2\cdots))$ has a unique value that is constrained in a convergent manner by the set $a_0$ as $\omega$ approaches $\infty$, when there are infinitely many $-1$s in $\epsilon$.

We see that regardless of whether there are finitely many (at least one) or infinitely many $-1$s in $\epsilon$, the expression converges.

Comment: Hi Marcus, first of all, thank you for your elaborate answer! I will read it later and give it the due credit. I just realised something very unfortunate. Do you agree with the part I just highlighted, for example?

Comment: "Do you agree with the part I just highlighted, for example?"
I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hello again @MarcusLuebke, thanks for the great answer! I just have a few questions: $(1)$I'm still only a beginner in using ordinals for mathematical proofs, so I'll trust you that the sort of reverse transfinite induction you did is correct. But one thing I know from ordinal arithmetic is that a strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals is finite, so although I viscerally understand what you did, it seems contradictory. I wonder if one couldn't just say by the same argument that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N s.t. \forall n\geq N, \mu(a)<\epsilon$ and get the result that way. (to be continued

Comment: $(2)$ You then prove $E(d,a)$ is a contraction. Unfortunately, I didn't understand the sentence about the "catch-points": you already proved $\mu(E(d,a))<\mu(a)$ occurs in the "worst case", so it seems obvious to me that iterating, you would get $\mu(a)=0$. (3) It seems that you have proven $a=\lbrace x\rbrace, x\in\mathbb{\bar R}$ but doesn't that mean possibly $a={\infty}$ for example?

Comment: $(2)$ You then prove $E(d,a)$ is a contraction. Unfortunately, I didn't understand the sentence about the "catch-points": you already proved $\mu(E(d,a))<\mu(a)$ occurs in the "worst case", so it seems obvious to me that iterating, you would get $\mu(a)=0$. $(3)$ It seems that you have proven $a=\lbrace x\rbrace, x\in\mathbb{\bar R}$ but doesn't that mean possibly $a=\lbrace +\infty \rbrace$ for example?

Comment: Lastly, about my last comment two days ago, I had spotted a mistake in my post, read the comments there for more details. Hope you can clear these up for me! And again, thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 4):

Marcus Luebke's answer is correct and he fully deserves the bounty. I think there is a clearer way to prove this and there's more to be said about the limiting distribution, so I'm posting my solution. As an aside, this is by far the most fun I have ever had answering a question on this site - thank you for asking such an interesting one!

**Theorem 1:** The power tower $e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\epsilon_2 e^{\epsilon_3 e^{\cdots}}}}$ converges for all sequences $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $\epsilon_n = -1$ for at least one $n$.

**Proof:** As you note, $e^{-e^{-e^{-e^\cdots}}}$ converges. Hence if only finitely many of $\epsilon_n =1$, the power tower converges. If only finitely many are $-1$, then the tower ends in a tail of $e^{e^{e^\cdots}} = \infty$, so after the last $-1$, you will have $e^{-e^{e^\cdots}} = 0$, and the tower clearly converges.

If there are infinitely many $1$'s and $-1$'s, it's a little bit trickier to prove convergence. In this case, it suffices to show that the tower converges if $\epsilon_1 = -1$. We choose a subsequence $n_k$ such that $n_1=1$ and for all $k>1$, $\epsilon_{n_k} = -1 = -\epsilon_{n_k - 1}$, and furthermore $n_{k} - n_{k-1} \ge 2$. Such a subsequence exists by the assumption that $\epsilon_n$ changes sign infinitely often. Now define:$$
f_k(x) = e^{\epsilon_{n_{k}}e^{\cdots^{e^{\epsilon_{n_{k+1}-1} x}}}}
$$
Therefore the $(n_{k+1}-1)$th power tower is $$
f_1(f_2(\cdots f_k(e)\cdots))
$$
Now observe the following properties of $f_k:$

- $f_k(x)$ is non-negative and monotonic in $x$.
- $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_k(x) \le 1$.
- $\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_k(x) \ge 0$
- For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can bound the derivative $|f_k'(x)| \le \frac1e$. (See footnote (1) for proof of this fact)

Let $g_k = f_1\circ f_2 \circ f_3 \cdots \circ f_k$. Then observe if $N > n_{k+1}$ there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$
e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\epsilon_2 e^{\cdots^{\epsilon_{N}e}}}} = g_k(x)
$$
so it suffices to show that the range of $g_k(x)$ converges to single point. The bound on the derivative of $f_k$ implies $|g_k'(x)|\le e^{-k}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which is almost good enough (uniform convergence of the derivatives to $0$ implies if $g_k(x)$ converges to a function, it converges uniformly to a constant function).

Notice that for each $k$, $g_k$ is either an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ or a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $M_k = \sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_k(x)$ and $m_k = \inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_k(x)$. Clearly both are finite for all $k\ge 1$. For $k$ such that $g_k$ is increasing:$$
M_{k+1} = \sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_{k+1}(x) = \sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_{k}(f_k(x))= g_k\left(\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)\right) \le g_k(1)
$$
and similarly $$
m_k =\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_{k+1}(x) = \inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} g_{k}(f_k(x)) = g_k\left(\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)\right) \ge g_k(0)
$$
These imply that there exist $x_k,y_k\in [0,1]$ such that $M_{k+1} = g_k(x_k)$ and $m_{k+1} = g_k(y_k)$. For $k$ such that $g_k$ is decreasing we similarly have have \begin{eqnarray}
m_{k+1} \ge g_k(1)\\
M_{k+1} \le g_k(0)
\end{eqnarray}
and so we can again pick $x_k,y_k\in[0,1]$ such that $M_{k+1} = g_k(x_k)$ and $m_{k+1} = g_k(y_k)$. Since $|g'_k(x)| \le e^{-k}$, we have $|g_k(x_k) - g_k(y_k)| \le e^{-k}|x_k - y_k| \le e^{-k}$, so the above conditions for $M_k$ and $m_k$ imply $M_{k+1} - m_{k+1} \le e^{-k}$ for all $k$. Furthermore, we have \begin{eqnarray}
M_{k+1} &=& g_k(x_k) \le M_k\\
m_{k+1} &=& g_k(y_k) \ge m_k
\end{eqnarray}
hence $M_k$ decreases and $m_k$ increases. This, together with the fact $M_k>m_k$, implies both $M_k$ and $m_k$ converge to a limit, but we also know $M_k - m_k \le e^{-k} \rightarrow 0$, so they converge to the same limit, implying $g_k(x)$ converges uniformly to a constant function, which in turn implies convergence of the power tower. $\blacksquare$

This implies that the probabilistic power tower converges almost surely as long as $-1$ almost surely occurs somewhere in the sequence $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\dots$ But what numbers are possible limits of such a sequence? It turns out that *any* nonnegative number is, as shown by this result:

**Theorem 2:** For all $x\in [0,\infty)$ there exists a sequence of $\epsilon_n$'s such that the corresponding power tower converges to $x$ in the limit.

**Proof:** Let $x\in [0,\infty)$. Define $x_n(t)$ recursively by \begin{eqnarray}
x_0(t) &=& t \\
x_{n+1}(t) &=&\begin{cases} x_n(e^{t}) & x_n(0) < x, x_n'(t)>0 \\ x_n(-e^{t}) & x_n(0) \ge x, x_n'(t)>0\\
x_n(-e^{t}) & x_n(0) < x, x_n'(t) < 0\\
x_n(e^t) & x_n(0) \ge x, x_n'(t) < 0\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
By theorem 1, $x_n(t)$ converges uniformly to a limit. Note that $x_n(1)$ is a power tower of type $e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots^{\pm e}}}}$, and also $x_n(t)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on its whole domain. We would like to show $x_n(t)\rightarrow x$, which will prove existence. Let $A_n = \sup x_n(t)$ and $B_n = \inf x_n(t)$. Observe that $A_0 \ge x \ge B_0$.

Claim: For all $n$, $x\in [B_n,A_n]$. We prove by induction. Assuming it is true for $n$, we have four cases.

1. If $x_n(0) < x$ and $x_n'(t)>0$: Then $x_{n+1}(t) = x_n(e^t)$ so $A_{n+1} = x_n(\infty) = A_n \ge x$ and $B_{n+1} = x_n(0) < x$.
2. If $x_n(0) \ge x$ and $x_n'(t)>0$: Then $x_{n+1}(t) = x_n(-e^{t})$ so $A_{n+1} = x_n(0) = A_n \ge x$ and $B_{n+1} = x_n(-\infty) = B_n \le x$.
3. If $x_n(0) < x$ and $x_n'(t) < 0$: Then $x_{n+1}(t) = x_n(-e^{t})$ so $A_{n+1}=x_n(-\infty) = A_n \ge x$ and $B_{n+1} = x_n(0) < x$.
4. If $x_n(0) \ge x$ and $x_n'(t) < 0$: Then $x_{n+1}(t) = x_n(e^t)$ so $A_{n+1}=x_n(0) \ge x$ and $B_{n+1} = x_n(\infty) = B_n \le x$.

This shows that $x_n(t) \rightarrow x$ for all $t$. In particular $x_n(1)\rightarrow x$, so there exists $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $$
x = e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\epsilon_2 e^{\epsilon_3 e^{\cdots}}}}
$$
$\blacksquare$

The representation is not in fact unique (as I claimed in a previous version). A countable set of numbers have two possible representations. For example:$$
1 = e^{e^{-e^{e^{e^{e^\cdots}}}}} = e^{-e^{-e^{e^{e^{e^\cdots}}}}} = e^0
$$
and similarly any finite-height power tower of the form $e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots ^{\pm e}}}}}$ corresponds to exactly two representations. It is not hard to show that for all numbers not of this form, the representation as an infinite power tower $e^{\pm e^\cdots}$ is unique.

---

For the rest of this answer, I'll examine your particular distribution where $\epsilon_n$ are i.i.d. with $\epsilon_n =\begin{cases}1 & \mbox{ w.p. } p \\ -1& \mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}$, where $0<p<1$. In your notation,$$
P_\epsilon = e^{\epsilon_1 e^{\epsilon_2 e^{\cdots}}}
$$
is the limiting distribution of the power tower.

**Theorem 3:** $$
\mathbb{E} P_\epsilon = \infty
$$

**Proof:** The probability that $(\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n) = (1,\cdots,1)$ is $p^n$. Hence we have probability $p^n$ of observing $$P_\epsilon = \exp^n\left(e^{\epsilon_{n+1}e^{\cdots}}\right)$$
where $\exp^n$ represents the $n$th iteration of $\exp$. We therefore have at least a $p^n$ probability of observing $$
P_\epsilon \ge \exp^n(0) = {{^{(n-1)}}e}
$$
hence, using the fact that $P_\epsilon \ge 0$, we observe for all $n$: $$
\mathbb{E} P_\epsilon \ge {p^n} \left({{^{n-1}}e}\right)
$$
Since [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) grows faster than exponentiation decays, this is unbounded in $n$ so $\mathbb{E}P_\epsilon = \infty$.$\blacksquare$

Since we have tetrational growth of $P_\epsilon$, it makes sense to look at instead the expectation of its [super-logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm). To avoid problems with how to interpolate tetration for non-integer values, we can look at $\lfloor\mathrm{slog}(P_\epsilon)\rfloor$, which is well-defined and does not depend on choice of interpolation:

**Theorem 4:** $$
\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor = \frac{2p-1}{1-p}
$$
**Proof:** Observe that for any $x<0$, $\mathrm{slog}(x) \in (-2,-1)$. Hence:\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor &=& \mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( e^{uP_\epsilon})\rfloor \\&=& 1+\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}(u P_\epsilon)\rfloor\\ &=&
1+p\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor+(1-p)\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( -P_\epsilon)\rfloor\\
&=& 1+p\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor +(1-p)(-2)\\
&=& 2p-1 + p\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor
\end{eqnarray}
Solving for $\mathbb{E}\lfloor\mathrm{slog}( P_\epsilon)\rfloor$ gives the desired result.$\blacksquare$

In fact, one can show $\lfloor\mathrm{slog}(P_\epsilon)\rfloor$ has a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with a shift.

---

I'll conclude by looking at some other properties of the limiting distribution:

Recall that $P_\epsilon \stackrel{d}{=} e^{u P_\epsilon}$ where $u$ is independent of $\epsilon$ with distribution but has the same distribution as each $\epsilon_j$. This gives us a way to compute the distribution function for $P_\epsilon$. Here I'm only going to consider the case of $p=\frac12$, but all of this can be generalized in a straightforward way.

The median of $P_\epsilon$ is $1$; $$
P(P_\epsilon \le 1) = \frac12
$$
because $P_\epsilon \le 1$ if and only if $\epsilon_1 = -1$.

In fact, we can compute explicit values for $P(P_\epsilon\le t)$ for many other values of $t$. Note that any $x$ can only be represented by at most two distinct sequences of $\epsilon_n$, so $P_\epsilon$ has no atoms. We can actually solve semi-explicitly for the distribution function $P_\epsilon$ because $P_\epsilon$ has the same distribution as $e^{u P_\epsilon}$. This gives us $$
P(P_\epsilon \le t) = P(e^{u P_\epsilon} \le t) = \frac12P(e^{P_\epsilon} \le t) + \frac12 P(e^{-P_\epsilon} \ge t) = \frac12 P(P_\epsilon \le \log t) + \frac12 P(-P_\epsilon \le \log t) = \frac12 P(P_\epsilon \le \log t) + \frac12 P(P_\epsilon \ge -\log t) 
$$
Letting $F(t) = P(P_\epsilon\le t)$ be the distribution function, we therefore have $$
F(t) = \frac12 F(\log t) + \frac12(1-F(-\log t)) = \frac12\left(1 + F(\log t) - F(-\log t)\right)
$$
Since $F(t) = 0$ for $t\ge 0$, this is equivalent to $$
F(t) = \frac12 + \frac12\mathrm{sgn}(\log t) F(|\log t|)
$$
as long as $t\ne 1$. This allows us to explicitly compute some values of $F$. For instance we can find $F(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\approx 0.56714...$ is the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant): $F(\Omega) = \frac12-\frac12F(\Omega)$ implies $F(\Omega) = \frac13$. This formula actually allows us to compute $F(t)$ effectively by iterating $t\to |\log t|$. Letting $L_n(t)$ be defined recursively by $L_{n+1}(t) = L_n(|\log t|)$, with $L_1(t) = \log t$, one can see:$$
F(t) = \frac12 + \frac{\mathrm{sgn}({L_1(t)})}4 +\frac{\mathrm{sgn}({L_2(t)})\mathrm{sgn}({L_1(t)})}8 + \cdots + \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(L_1(t))\cdots\mathrm{sgn}(L_m(t))}{2^{m+1}}F(|L_m(t)|) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\prod_{k=1}^n \mathrm{sgn}(L_k(t))}{2^{n+1}}
$$
The dynamics of $L_n(t)$ are pretty chaotic. Since $|\log t|$ has [periodic points with period $3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7Clog%20%7C%20log%20%7C%20log%20x%20%7C%20%7C%20%7C%20%3D%20x), [Sharkovskii's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem) implies that it has points of all periods.<sup>(2)</sup>

The value of $F$ may be computed explicitly for any periodic point. For example, take the 2-periodic pair $(a,b) = (0.269874...,1.30980...)$. Then we have \begin{eqnarray}
F(a) = \frac12 - \frac12 F(b)\\
F(b) = \frac12 + \frac12 F(a)
\end{eqnarray}
which has solution $F(a) = \frac15$ and $F(b) = \frac35$.

Here's a graph of the function (computed using by summing the first 20 terms of the series):
[image: graph of F(t)]

It looks weird and fractal-ish. In fact:

**Theorem 5:** $F(t)$ is non-differentiable on a dense set.

**Proof:** First we show $F$ is not differentiable at $t=0$:$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{F(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1-F(-\log h)}{2h} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-F(x)}{2e^{-x}}
$$
If this limit converged, then $1-F(x)$ would have a finite integral by the comparison test, but because $\int_0^\infty \left(1-F(x)\right) dx= \mathbb E P_\epsilon  = \infty $, this is impossible. Hence $F$ is not differentiable at $0$. This implies $F$ is not differentiable at any point of the form $$
e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots^{\pm e}}}}
$$
because all such points go to $0$ under finitely many applications of $t\to |\log(t)|$, and hence the recursion formula implies $F$ is non-differentiable at those points. By Theorem 2 above, the set of those points is dense in $[0,\infty)$, so thus $F$ is non-differentiable on a dense subset of $[0,\infty)$. $\blacksquare$

---

**Footnotes:**

**(1)** $f_k(x)$ is always a composition of at least two exponential functions $x\to e^{\pm x}$ such that the first is $e^{-x}$ and the last is $e^x$, i.e. $f$ has the form $$
f_k(x) = e^{- e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\cdots ^{\pm e^x}}}}}
$$
One can see that $f$ consists of some number of compositions of functions of the form $e^{-x}$ or $$
e^{- e^{e^{\cdots^x}}} = e^{-\exp^j(x)}
$$
where $\exp^j(x)$ represents $j$ iterations of $\exp(x)$ for some $j\ge 1$. Furthermore, since the innermost function is of the latter form, all of the instances of $e^{-x}$ are evaluated at positive arguments. Since $\left|\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x}\right|\le 1$ for positive arguments, it suffices to show that $\left|\frac{d}{dx} e^{-\exp^j(x)}\right| \le \frac1e$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j\ge 1$. For $j=1$, we have $|\frac{d}{dx} e^{-\exp^j(x)}| = e^x e^{-e^x}$ which is [maximized at $x=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum%20of%20e%5Ex%20e%5E%28-e%5Ex%29). One can show that this is the largest the derivative can be for any higher value of $j$ For higher values of $j$, we have $$
|\hat f_k'(x)| = e^x e^{e^x} \cdots \exp^j(x) e^{-\exp^j(x)} =\exp\left(x + e^x + \cdots + \exp^{j-1}(x) - \exp^j(x)\right)
$$
By observing that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have [$2e^t - e^{e^t} < 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum%20of%202e%5Ex-e%5Ee%5Ex), we must have $$
x + e^x + \cdots + \exp^{j-1}(x) - \exp^j(x) = x + e^x + \cdots + \exp^{j-2}(x) -\exp^{j-1}(x) + 2\exp^{j-1}(x) - \exp^j(x) < x + e^x + \cdots + \exp^{j-2}(x) -\exp^{j-1}(x)
$$
hence the sequence of maximum derivatives is decreasing in $j$, so in particular, all of them are bounded by $\frac1e$ as claimed.

**(2)** Sharkovskii's theorem is not strictly applicable to $|\log t|$ as a real-valued function, since has an infinite value at $t=0$. However, it *is* continuous on the extended reals as a function from $[0,\infty]$ to itself, so the theorem applies.